# Chrome extension doesn't run

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, frontend

I'm trying to make an extension for Google Chrome.

I created the files `manifest.json` and `popup.html`. My problem is that I can't test my extension, in fact, I only have the icon. When I click on it, well, nothing happens, no message, no popup, no error, nothing.

Here is my code:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":" empire",
    "description":"test",
    "version":"1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "http://*.google.com/"
    ],
    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon":"img/icon/logo.png",
        "popup":"popup.html"
    }
}
```

My html has just a "Hello world" string.

Does anyone have a solution for me? Thank you!

Comment: Check chrome://extensions for errors. Also, right-click on your extension's icon and select Inspect Popup to open the popup's developer tools and check for errors there.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your answer. The problem is I have no errors, and I can't use the inspector tool, it's grey, options is grey too, and even if I don't set the line  "popup":"popup.html", I have no errors and no window open when I click on the extension ..

Comment: Change `"popup":"popup.html"` for `"default_popup":"popup.html"`. Check the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

Comment: What an idiot ... Thank you very much, it's the solution !